# Assigning Hardware Button to Wake and Trigger In-App Functionality

Tags: android, android-source

I have a device which is running a slightly modified version of AOSP, I am also removing the default Launcher and other apps so that only my application runs.

The device has a second hardware button which we would like to trigger an "in-app" event, it should wake the device, show a new activity and perform some HTTP events through the application layer. It's currently assigned to the back button but I guess I need to add a custom key input event but not sure where to start.

Has anyone tried to do something similar / any ideas on where to start?

Was thinking of trying to cause the back button to create a wake event so that the app will receive the OnBackPressed even when the device is asleep though I'm not sure that is the best way to approach it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Ensure that your additional hardware button generates a suitable Linux key event. Read http://newandroidbook.com/Book/Input.html if you're unsure about how to check this. If the button doesn't yet trigger key events or if it the key code is unsuitable, then you'd have to add/edit the device tree overlay. This has little to do with android but is specific to your hardware. You likely find some help in the linux related documentation of your hardware
2. Then you'd map that linux keycode to an android key event using an android key layout file. There, the WAKE flag needs to be added in order for the device to wake up and pass the event to your app. The relevant chapter of the AOSP help is this one: https://source.android.com/devices/input/key-layout-files
3. Intercept the key event in your android app (it sounds like you already managed to do this)